# DataFrame.at creates a new row instead of inserting value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that loops through two lists, makes API calls based on the values contained in those lists and then merges responses into a single dataframe as below:

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame()
links = [109340678,60375713,...]
ids = [353474,184335,...]
for id in ids:
    url = "https://myurl/{}.json".format(id)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(response.content)
    data = json_obj['data']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df = df.set_index('field').T 
    df = df.replace(to_replace='.*patern.*', value=np.NaN, regex=True) # replace a particular pattern with NaN, insert content from the loop below
    for link in links:
        url_download= "https://myurl/{id}/{link}".format(id= id, link= link)
        response = requests.get(url_act, headers=headers)
        df.at[0,link] = response.content
    master_df = master_df.append(df)
```

I save the results in an Excel workbook, but get the following, where *value* is the response.content
[image]

I inspected every iteration of the loop and can't quite understand why, despite specifying 0 as row index, I get and extra row created every time.

Comment: df.at[0,link], its supposed to create a new column. no?

Comment: No, link corresponds to an existing column

Comment: link is also a variable in your for loop. your question is not clear. please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've made a mistake in the description. My problem is that the df.at[] property creates an extra row index[1], instead of inserting the value at index[0] as specified